# Subsitute for Month,year,date functions in jpa

Tags: java, jpa, orm, jpql

I want to execute this query in JPA.But i am getting error while executing this query.How to use Month(),Year() in JPA
We can use these in native  SQL Query.But how to use it?
Please help me.Thanks in advance!!

```
 select model from IptExchangeratelines model where model.iptExchangerate.id=:id and " +
                " month(model.currencyExchangeDate)=:month and year(model.currencyExchangeDate)=:year
```

Comment: What error are you getting exactly?

Comment: I am getting unknown token "MONTH" error

Comment: Could you post the Stack trace, if you have one? And the line of your source code that's throwing the exception.

Answer (score 12):

Few JPA implementations have built-in support for date/time functions.

- **EclipseLink**

  > EclipseLink supports EXTRACT allowing any database supported date/time part value to be 
  >   extracted from the date/time. The EXTRACT function is database independent, but requires database support.

  `EXTRACT(YEAR, model.currencyExchangeDate)`, but it requires EclipseLink 2.4.x

  > **FUNC** allows for a database function to be call from JPQL. It allows calling any  database functions not supported directly in JPQL.

  To call the DB function `MyFunc(a, b, c)` use `FUNC('MyFunc', a, b, c)`.

  You can try `FUNC('YEAR', currencyExchangeDate)` to call 'YEAR' function.
- **Hibernate**

  In HQL, you can have date function `YEAR(date)`, `MONTH(date)`, `DAY(date)` to extract required details.
  Other time functions supported are `HOUR(date)`, `MINUTE(date)`, `SECOND(date)`.
- **Criteria API**

  > **CriteriaBuilder#function() :** Create an expression for the execution of a database function.

  `CriteriaQuery<IptExchangeratelines> cq = cb.createQuery(IptExchangeratelines.class);
  Root<IptExchangeratelines> exRateLine = cq.from(IptExchangeratelines.class);
  cq.where(cb.equal(cb.function("year", Integer.class,

  exRateLine.get(exRateLine_.currencyExchangeDate)), year)
  .and(cb.equal(cb.function("month", Integer.class,
  exRateLine.get(exRateLine_.currencyExchangeDate)), month)));`

Comment: I have also tried the extract but i am getting unknown token -EXTRACT.We are using JPA 2.0

Comment: Which provider/version?  For EclipseLink you need 2.4.

Answer (score 1):

DataNucleus JPA jhas built in support for YEAR, MONTH, DAY, HOUR, MINUTE, SECOND, as well as the JPA 2.1 standard "FUNCTION" for invoking native functions in the RDBMS.

In my experience ALL JPA implementations support such things, unlike the impression given by the other answer

Answer (score 0):

Dears,

sometimes we have to think with different way, maybe this can help:

```
TypedQuery<Number> query = entityManager.createQuery(
                "SELECT SUM(COALESCE(p.amount, 0)) FROM Payment p WHERE p.paymentDate BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2", Number.class);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month -1);
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);

        query.setParameter(1, calendar.getTime());
        //the location is very important
        calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        calendar.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, -1);

        query.setParameter(2, calendar.getTime());
        return query.getSingleResult().doubleValue();
```