# Filtering in query using JPA in java

Tags: java, sql, jpa, ejb

How to fetch data on the basis of YEAR using openjpa from database. I have a timestamp(RECEIPT_DATE) field in my database. Now i went to fetch the data from the database on the basis of selected year.
Query is as below:

```
select contact_names from contact where YEAR(RECEIPT_DATE)='2014'.
```

This works perfectly in database.

The same i wrote in JPA like this.

```
select contactNames from contact where year(receiptDate)='2014'.
```

But i get an error like Year Arguement cannot be recognized.
Is there any way to how can i perform the same query using JPA preferably not making use of any additional plugins for the same. Please guide.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subsitute for Month,year,date functions in jpa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15802989/subsitute-for-month-year-date-functions-in-jpa)

Comment: @Jens: There is no accepted answer for the link mentioned and i have tried the methodologies there which did not seem to work for me too(Supposedly the post mentions to use nativeQuery but i am asking are there any inbuilt functions in JPA rather than to use native query).

Answer (score 0):

You should use the JPA Criteria API Queries. They have functions to extract the year of a date. and it's helpful because if you make a mistake you know it on compile time instead on runtime.

Comment: Criteria does NOT have specific functions to extract year etc (and neither does JPQL) - criteria has exactly what JPQL string form has. JPA 2.1 has added "FUNCTION" as I put in my answer which could be used to invoke native functions.

Comment: @Neil Stockton Maybe i read wrong but on this site:[link]http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/date They talk about the functions for extracting date and time parts available in criteria queries. Example: cb.function("year", Integer.class, date);

Comment: but yes it's not getYear

Comment: As I said, JPA 2.1 has "FUNCTION", and that is part of JPQL string based querying, and also Criteria. That is no reason for the user to have to use Criteria, since the method is not only available there ... he can just put it in his string query. As per my answer, the 'function' is totally RDBMS-specific.

Answer (score 0):

JPA does not have the YEAR function, with JPA you will use JPQL and not SQL.

You could use NativeQuery instead:

entityManager.createNativeQuery("select * name from person", RESULT_CLASS.class);

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html

Answer (score 0):

JPA 2.1 has `FUNCTION(funcName, args)` and you can set the FUNCTION to *YEAR* (or whatever your RDBMS supports). It has no specific functions for date components, so you have to look up the specific native functions used by your RDBMS and put them into JPA2.1 "FUNCTION"