# JPA Query Language: any function for extracting date (e.g. 2014-09-12) from a Date field?

Tags: jpa

I am using JPA Query Language to retrieve data from the database. This is my class mapped to the database.

```
class Test {
  Long id;
  Date date;
}
```

I need to count the number of records for each date (such as 2014-09-12) through group by. I cannot seem to find a function that allow me to change a date (having values in hour, minute, etc.) into a string in the format of 2014-09-12 or removing a date's hour, minute, second, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: I am afraid some JPA implementations will have their proprietary extensions with time functions for JPA, but this may vary. What JPA implementation are you using?

Comment: Leo, thanks for your input! I am doing development on MSSQL and Hibernate 4.3.6.Final. I may migrate the system to Oracle for production. Again, thanks!!!

Comment: take a look at Brian's answer in this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/639522/performing-date-time-math-in-hql -- it's not the accepted answer, but I think it's pretty much useful. It's HQL, not JPQL, but may work.

Comment: also take a look at Nayan's answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15802989/subsitute-for-month-year-date-functions-in-jpa

Comment: Leo, thanks for links you provided. I am going to create a field/column for storing the date (without hour/minute/second/millisecond) for count and grouping purpose. I have a lot of computation need for this grouping by date, and manipulating a date field is both convoluted and impacts performance badly. Kind of duplicate, but works. Cheers!

Comment: this may be a good solution, actually :-)